# Java template question

Tags: java, generics, function

I have instantiated an object like this:

```
GraphMatrixDirected<String, Integer> g
```

g is passed to a function like this:

```
floyd(g);
```

floyd's signature looks like this:

```
public void floyd(GraphMatrixDirected<V,E> g)
```

Eclipse gives me an error saying:

`The method floyd(GraphMatrixDirected<V,E>) in the type GraphMatrix<V,E> is not applicable for the arguments (GraphMatrixDirected<String,Integer>)`

What do I need to do to fix it?

Edit1:

```
abstract public class GraphMatrix<V,E> extends AbstractStructure<V> implements Graph<V,E>
```

Edit2:

```
public interface Graph<V,E> extends Structure<V>

public abstract class AbstractStructure<E> implements Structure<E>

public interface Structure<E> extends Iterable<E>
/* JDT added extension of Iterable for Java 5 */
```

Edit 3:
Note: Funtion was changed from `floyd` to `AllPairsShortestPath`.

```
public void AllPairsShortestPath(GraphMatrixDirected<V,E> g) 
// post: g contains edge (a,b) if there is a path from a to b 
{
    Iterator<V> witer = g.iterator();
    while (witer.hasNext()) 
    {
        Iterator<V> uiter = g.iterator();
        V w = witer.next(); 

        while (uiter.hasNext())
        {
            Iterator<V> viter = g.iterator(); 
            V u = uiter.next(); 

            while (viter.hasNext()) 
            {
                V v = viter.next(); 

                if (g.containsEdge(u,w) && g.containsEdge(w,v)) 
                {
                    Edge<V,E> leg1 = g.getEdge(u,w);
                    Edge<V,E> leg2 = g.getEdge(w,v); 

                    Integer leg1Dist = (Integer)leg1.label(); 
                    Integer leg2Dist = (Integer)leg2.label(); 
                    Integer newDist = (Integer)leg1Dist+leg2Dist;

                    E newDistE = (E)newDist;

                    if (g.containsEdge(u,v)) 
                    {
                        Edge<V,E> across = g.getEdge(u,v);
                        Integer acrossDist = (Integer)across.label(); 

                        if (newDist < acrossDist)
                        {
                            across.setLabel(newDistE);
                        } 
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        g.addEdge(u,v,newDistE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The definitions of V and E are probably class-wide, right? Does they include any restriction, like having to extend any classes?

Comment: Yea, they are class wide (I think??). How do I know?

Comment: If they are defined in the class declaration, they are class wide. If they are defined in the method declaration (see answers below), then they are method-wide.

Comment: Ok, then yes, they are class wide as I show with the edit.

Comment: Can you post the code of the class declarations of AbstractStructure and Graph? If @dimitris-andreou is not right, I guess the problem is exactly what I first thought: V and E have to extend some class, thus can't be String and Integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you meant `floyd` to be a generic method?

```
public <V,E> void floyd(GraphMatrixDirected<V,E> g)
```

Otherwise, whatever generic type `floyd` is a member of need to have `<V,E>` parameterized as `<String,Integer>`.

If it's true that `floyd` belongs to a generic type, and yet `floyd` also needs to be a generic method with its own type parameters, you may want to choose different names, so as not to hide one another.

#### References

- [Java Tutorials/Generics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/)
- [Angelika Langer's Java Generic FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

  - [Generic Types](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html) and [Generic Methods](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedMethods.html)

---

#### On generic type vs generic methods

The choice between which solution route to take depends on what `floyd` does and other things. One essential question is this: do you consider `floyd` to be a method that belongs specifically to the generic type `GraphMatrixDirected<V,E>` (answer is probably no) or is it rather a generic utility method that works with any `Graph<V,E>`? (answer is probably yes).

For example and guidance, we can also take a look at how Java Collections Framework is structured:

- [`interface List<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) - a generic type that defines basic functionality for the type

  - specifies `boolean add(E e)`, `E get(int index)`, etc
- [`class Collections`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) - provides `static` utility generic methods

  - `static void shuffle(List<?> list)`
  - `static <T` <sub>`extends Comparable<? super T>>`</sub> `void sort(List<T> list)`
  - `static <T` <sub>`extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>`</sub> `T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)`

Assuming that `floyd` is indeed an implementation of [Floyd-Warshall all-pairs shortest path algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd-Warshall), I'd argue that it should be a `static` utility method to say a `Graphs` class, and works with any `Graph<V,E>`.

#### See also, *Effective Java 2nd Edition*

Generic types vs methods:

- Item 26, Favor generic types
- Item 27, Favor generic methods

Interfaces:

- Item 18, Prefer interfaces to abstract classes
- Item 19, Use interfaces only to define types
- Item 52, Refer to objects by their interfaces

Comment: The link to "Angelika Langer's Java Generic FAQs" has a typo. The correct URL is:
http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html

Comment: @Jim: thanks for correction; noted. Will revise on my own along with more update once I have enough information about the question.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Do you see anything new now?

Comment: @00PS: I didn't see anything new from YOU. Did you read the FAQs I linked to especially with regards to generic types vs generic methods? Anyway, I'll try to provide more info but unless you give more info and/or do your own reading, I can only guess at what's happening.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: What else would you like to see? I'm a little unsure about how I can fix my code.

Comment: @00PS: if you can post `floyd` method in its entirety, we can comment whether or not it should be a generic `static` utility method. I'm 90% confident that it is.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Here it is.

Comment: @00PS: try `public static <V,E> void AllPairsShortestPath(GraphMatrixDirected<V,E> g)` for a quick-fix attempt for now; however, I will comment on the code in more detail tomorrow. There's a lot to cover, e.g. for-each loop, preferring primitives to boxed primitives, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
public <V, E> void floyd(GraphMatrixDirected<V,E> g)
```

(This should probably be static too).

Otherwise, we would have to see how you create the object containing this method, and in particular what types you assign to V and E (if V was String and E was Integer, it would work, but apparently it isn't).

I understand you have something like

```
class GraphMatrixDirected<V,E> extends GraphMatrix<V,E> { ... }
```

Then you could keep the method signature as you had it (actually if it is defined in GraphMatrixDirected and it is an instance method, you **probably** don't want another GraphMatrixDirected parameter to it, but just use `this`), and just use:

```
GraphMatrixDirected<String, Integer> g = new GraphMatrixDirected<String, Integer>();
```

Note that I don't endorse this design, but this is beyond the point.

Comment: This is what I currently have now, and it is erroneous.